# How to make dropdown menu ? [JS or RoR]

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to implement dropdown menu within rails checkout form.
This is html of dropdown

```
<select name="address_id" id="address-select" class="address-select" title="" onChange="bil.newAddress(!this.value)">
   <option value="1" selected="selected">John Doe, main tower, United States</option>
   <option value="">New Address</option>
 </select>
```

If option one is selected, these values(of logged in user) will be used(that's not a problem), but if the second one is selected I want to additional form be shown, so that user can populate it.

I know i can achieve this in JS but want to know is this possible in ruby on rails(with or without refreshing page)

Comment: In any case, you need to use JS/jQuery if you don't want to post information to the server to get another page. In the case of JS, you need an `on change` trigger that will handle the visibility of additional form. 
It really depends on what you need. In this case, I would go with JS, and just submitting the form through Rails.

Comment: Yes .@ZlatkoAlomerovic is correct. Rails has served the page to the browser. Any action that you need to now perform on the browser has to be triggered via the browser. You could either have a form submit on selecting the dropdown, in which case rails will look at the user input and serve another page or you will have to write Javascript that will show/add elements to the page based on the selection made.